# mongodb import multiple collections at once

Tags: mongodb, mongoimport, mongoexport

I am using this command

> mongoimport --db databasename

to import a database that I exported using mongoexport.
The database has over 100 collections in the mongoimport documentation you need to specify the collection name and json file.
How do I go about importing all the collections at once without having to type a command for each collection

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the documentation

> New in version 2.6: If you do not specify --collection, mongoimport
>   takes the collection name from the input filename. MongoDB omits the
>   extension of the file from the collection name, if the input file has
>   an extension.

So it seems it is supposed to do import one collection at a time. So unless you write a shell script to do it, I don't see a way.

mongodump and mongorestore are much better for taking full db dump and restore it at once as the other part of the same document says

> Warning
>
> Avoid using mongoimport and mongoexport for full instance production
>   backups. They do not reliably preserve all rich BSON data types,
>   because JSON can only represent a subset of the types supported by
>   BSON. Use mongodump and mongorestore as described in MongoDB Backup
>   Methods for this kind of functionality.

Comment: agree, do not use mongoimport or mongoexport on production, I had cases of loosing data when doing such operations

Answer (score 7):

It is very surprising that there isn't easy to find documentation on importing multiple collections. *Restoring* a database isn't always intuitive keyword when you are searching for it, but that is what you want to do when you want to restore a database from a backup. If you already have a dump of collections that you exported with `mongodump`, you should be able to use `mongorestore`.

This is all you really need to run:

```
mongorestore --db db_name ./db_dumpfiles/
```

Answer (score 4):

If dump files are in .json you can use the script for import

```
ls *.json | sed 's/.metadata.json//' | while read col; do mongoimport -d db_name -c $col < $col.metadata.json; done
```

If dump files are in .json.gz you can use the script for import

```
ls *.gz | sed 's/.metadata.json.gz//' | while read col; do mongoimport -d db_name --gzip -c $col < $col.metadata.json.gz; done
```

Comment: Thanks for this script. Saved me a lot of typing :)

Answer (score 3):

One simple command

```
mongorestore --db folder_name ./folder_name/
```